# how to unwrap an array in php

Tags: php, arrays, unwarp

i have this array here:

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
     (
         [presentation] => Präsentationen
     )

 [1] => Array
     (
         [news] => Aktuelle Meldungen
         [devplan] => Förderprogramme
         [salesdoc] => Vertriebsunterlagen
     )

 [2] => Array
     (
         [user/settings] => Mein Account
     )

 [3] => Array
     (
     )

 [4] => Array
     (
         [orders] => Projekte
     )

)
```

i want to unwrap the first depth of the array to get this:

```
 Array
 (
  [presentation] => Präsentationen
  [news] => Aktuelle Meldungen
  [devplan] => Förderprogramme
  [salesdoc] => Vertriebsunterlagen
  [user/settings] => Mein Account
  [orders] => Projekte
 )
```

Comment: nothing, i know some ways to do this, but the are all ugly :)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

With PHP 5.3.0+:

```
array_reduce($array, 'array_merge', array());
```

Comment: Beautiful one-liner, but I still have to go with Gordon's approach, it seems simpler to me.

Comment: I like this one better than mine, because it works for an arbitrary amount of arrays on the first level

Comment: wow this looks cool, but it doesnt work for me :( array_merge() [function.array-merge]: Argument #1 is not an array, but im 100% sure its the same array form the example.

Comment: Works perfectly here, but I have a different structure:
Before:
`array(2) {  [0]=>  array(1) {    ["a"]=>    int(1)  }  [1]=>  array(1) {    ["b"]=>    int(2)  }}`
After:
`array(2) {  ["a"]=>  int(1)  ["b"]=>  int(2)}`

Comment: I also wonder why this works, as I tried it myself in another context without success. In comments on the `array_reduce` documentation site, someone says: "If $initial parameter is not an int, array_reduce passes 0 (zero) to the callback function". This way exactly my problem. So why does it work in your case? Also the method signature says: `(array $input , callback $function [, int $initial ])` note **`int $initial`**.

Comment: I have PHP 5.3.1 here. It might be broken in some older versions.

Comment: Ok I think I found it, this was introduced in PHP 5.3.0 : "Changed array_reduce() to allow mixed $initial." Maybe you should put this in your answer.

Answer (score 5):

I guess the simplest way is to use a `foreach` loop:

```
 $resultArray = array();

  foreach ($myArray as $array)
   foreach ($array as $key => $element)
    $resultArray[$key] = $element;
```

Comment: @Pekka - yep, I'm just not with it today.

Comment: @karim79, that happens sometimes. But @Gordon beat us both, his solution is definitely the best.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
array_merge($array[0], $array[1], $array[2], $array[3], $array[4]);
```

or

```
$new = $array[0] + $array[1] + $array[2] + $array[3] + $array[4];
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also a beautifull one liner

```
$array = new RecursiveArrayIterator($yourArray);
```

Comment: this also doesn't work for me, it doesn't change the input array in any way.

Comment: You'd have to wrap that into an RecursiveIteratorIterator as well to be able to iterate over the first level elements. Also, $array won't be an array but, like the classname suggests, an iterator, wrapping an array.

Answer (score 1):

With PHP 5.6.0+:

```
$new = array_merge(...$array);
```

(A more general version of Gordons approach.)